# python-choose random member in one array and remove it in the other identical array

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, variables

i have 2 arrays, one is the main array, other is temp, that temp array chooses 1 random number and then its supposed to remove that member in the main array, since the content of both arrays is identical . how to do that ? down is the code

```
import random
spil=['1t','2t','3t','4t','5t','6t','7t','8t','9t','10t','12t','13t','14t'\
           ,'1k','2k','3k','4k','5k','6k','7k','8k','9k','10k','12k','13k','14k'\
           ,'1e','2e','3e','4e','5e','6e','7e','8e','9e','10e','12e','13e','14e'\
           '1p','2p','3p','4p','5p','6p','7p','8p','9p','10p','12p','13p','14p']
print(spil)
izvucena = random.sample(['1t','2t','3t','4t','5t','6t','7t','8t','9t','10t','12t','13t','14t'\
           ,'1k','2k','3k','4k','5k','6k','7k','8k','9k','10k','12k','13k','14k'\
           ,'1e','2e','3e','4e','5e','6e','7e','8e','9e','10e','12e','13e','14e'\
           '1p','2p','3p','4p','5p','6p','7p','8p','9p','10p','12p','13p','14p'],1)
spil.remove(izvucena)
print(spil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `random.sample` returns a list, you really want to do something like this:

```
izvucena = random.sample(spil, 1)[0] # grab only element from list returned
```

Although it'd be simpler to use `random.choice` instead:

```
izvucena = random.choice(spil)
```

Comment: im new to python programming but i too came to conclusion that it returns list, and i dont know how to convert it to a string or something, does random.choice returns string automatic?

Comment: No, `random.choice` returns the actual element from the list, it does not do any conversion. You can just grab the first element from the list using slice notation, as in my example above, if you want to use `random.sample`.

Comment: zeekay that worked, your random.choice suggestion works flawless :) thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `random.sample()` returns a list, not a single element, and in this case `izvucena` is a list with one element.  Just replace the second to last line with `spil.remove(izvucena[0])` to remove the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need the temporary list for something else, there really isn't any need for it to remove a random value, you could just do:

```
spil.remove(random.choice(spil))
```

Comment: i need that temporary variable to assign object attribute in a class, but thanks for answering, im sure that will me helpful to someone as well :)